# php send https rest request with headers

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2, request

I need to send a request to an api with auth headers

here is what I've tried so far

```
$client = new \yii\httpclient\Client(['baseUrl' => 'https://link']);
$response = $client->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->addHeaders(['authorization' => 'token'])
            ->send();
var_dump($response);
//other
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$headers = ['authorization' => 'token'];
$body = 'Hello!';
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'https://link', $headers, $body);
$response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 2]);
$curl = new \linslin\yii2\curl\Curl();

$response = $curl->setHeaders($headers)->get('link', $headers);
var_dump($response);

// other
$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "authorization:token\r\n",
    ],
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents('link', false, $context);
var_dump($file);

// other
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = ["authorization:token"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); # custom headers, see above
$result = curl_exec($ch); # run!
// curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

ps: I am working with the yii2 framework

so can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
{
    "client": {
        "baseUrl": null,
        "formatters": {
            "urlencoded": {
                "encodingType": 1,
                "charset": null
            }
        },
        "parsers": [],
        "requestConfig": [],
        "responseConfig": {
            "format": "json"
        },
        "contentLoggingMaxSize": 2000
    }
}
```

that is the error I am getting. I don't get any details regarding the connection ...

Comment: we cant tell whats wrong in your code until you tell whats the problem you are having

Comment: I will add a screenshot but tell me is it correctly written at least?

Comment: you are using 3 dff http clients guzzel,yii2 and then you are using curl too, guzzel http no longer requires cURL in order to send HTTP requests. Guzzle will use the PHP stream wrapper to send HTTP requests if `cURL` is not installed. Alternatively, you can provide your own HTTP handler used to send requests

Comment: i did not use them all at once i tried them one by one. the error is in description

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
$client = new \yii\httpclient\Client(['responseConfig' => [
            'format' => \yii\httpclient\Client::FORMAT_JSON,
        ]]);
        $response = $client->createRequest()
            ->setHeaders(['authorization' => 'f52d76cc976e0e1b6aa81c926cbc33823b5e5983', 'content-type' => 'application/json'])
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->setUrl('https://preprod-next-ngcvin5.ngc-data.fr/api/v1/vehicules/CR-157-NB')
            ->send();

        return $response->data;
```